# The two-lined text squishing horizontally a image of the same line

Tags: html, css, image, text, frontend

I have a component something like the image bellow

[example_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYeIJ.png)

On the left side has a circular image with a gray background and fixed width and height;
On the right side has a text with the title of the image

But when the title gets longer like showned in the screenshot, the image container gets squished horizontally. In the example above, the image should have 32x32 pixels, but it has 28x32, turning it oval instead of a sphere

The parent element of then two can streech vertically freely, are display: flex, and it has space for the two line text

Code of the image:

```html
<button style="display: flex; background-color: transparent; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor: pointer; border-width: 0px;align-items: center;width: 140px;">
<img  style="width: 32px;height: 32px;object-fit: contain;max-height: 32px;margin-right: 0.25rem;background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);justify-content: center;align-items: center;display: flex;border-radius: 100%;">
<span>Word biggger_word</span>
</button>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the image in another element. Try this

```
<button style="display: flex; background-color: transparent; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor: pointer; border-width: 0px;align-items: center;width: 140px;">
<span><img  style="width: 32px;height: 32px;object-fit: contain;max-height: 32px;margin-right: 0.25rem;background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);justify-content: center;align-items: center;display: flex;border-radius: 100%;"></span>
<span>Word biggger_word safsff sdfgdfg sdfgs dsfdsf</span>
</button>
```